# Circular Queue. Checking if it's full or not

Tags: c, data-structures, queue

I'm having issue with checking if my circular queue is full or not. The maximum size for the queue is set to 5. However, after putting in 4 elements, it doesn't let me add a fifth element. I'm stuck.

[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAy17.png)

```
void init (struct data* ptr) {
    ptr->rear = 0;
    ptr->front = 0;
}

void display (struct data* ptr) {
    if (empty(ptr)) {
        printf("\nNo data to display. The queue is EMPTY.\n");
    } else if (ptr->rear > ptr->front) {
        for (int i = ptr->front; i < ptr->rear; i++) {
            printf ("%d ", ptr->data[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < ptr->rear; i++) {
            printf("%d ", ptr->data[i]);
        }
        for (int i = ptr->front; i < MAX; i++) {
            printf("%d ", ptr->data[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

bool empty (struct data* ptr) {
    if (ptr->rear == ptr->front) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void enQueue (struct data* ptr, int input) {
    int nR = (ptr->rear + 1) % MAX;
    if (nR == ptr->front) {
        printf("\nQueue is FULL.\n\n");
    } else {
        ptr->data[ptr->rear] = input;
        ptr->rear = nR;
        printf("\nElement %d is inserted.\n\n", input);
    }
}
```

Comment: See [minimal complete reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You don't show us the structure, but I can guess that you don't have a count of elements in it, or an "empty" flag, which means that the head==tail condition (or what you are calling rear/front) cannot distinguish between an empty queue and a full one.

Comment: int data[MAX] is declared in the struct

Comment: The data structure has variables of type int for front and rear as well. Later, both initialized to 0 in a separate "init" function.

Comment: Then, as I said, you can't fill your queue because then front and rear would be equal, and you're using that to signal empty. You need either an empty flag, a fill count, or resign yourself to only ever having N-1 elements in the queue. You can't beat the pidgeonhole principle.

Comment: https://repl.it/join/qlgaxiws-maximaldaranov here is my code

Comment: parafleck, please edit your answer and show the errors or the structure there, not in the comments. It is not acceptable on StackOverflow to not provide insufficient data to diagnose the problem. Try to anticipate what people might need to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your queue has five elements, and rear can point to any of them. So front also can point to any of the five elements, and thus indicate five states. But if you want the queue to contain 0,1,2,3,4 or 5 items, that's six different states to distinguish. You're trying to put 6 pigeons into 5 pigeonholes.

To make a circular queue work, you have three choices: (1) add an "empty" or "full" flag to distinguish between those two states; (2) add a "fill count" which can also be used for that purpose; or (3) resign yourself to never putting more than N-1 items in your N-size queue.

Comment: What do you mean by a "flag"? Separate functions? What would be the conditions for such functions?

Comment: A "flag" is just a boolean variable.